# lua lanes communication between threads

Tags: windows, linux, multithreading, lua

Is there a way to for lua lanes threads to communicate or to access the threads from outside of it?

Without using busy loops like the documentation provides.

A simple example would be, a threads using a variable, updating it, changing it etc and another thread or the main program to be able to access/get that variable.

Is this possible with lua lanes?

And I mean purely in lua not from c/c++.

Answer (score 4):

While using multiple threads, you usually [do not want to "update/change" a variable from multiple threads without any synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Thread_and_fiber_issues) - this could lead to randomly appearing errors caused by unsynchronized access to variables/tables, etc.

Instead, you should rely on message passing to handle communication between threads. This is called the [actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) and is directly supported by some languages, like Erlang.

[LuaLanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/) also embraces this model of communication. To communicate between various lanes, you create a [Linda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_%28coordination_language%29) object, which can be shared by the main thread and spawned threads, and used to communicate. Linda objects handle synchronization for you, no locking from your side is required. Every operation (sending, receiving a message) is atomic.

> Without using busy loops...

Although it may seem like it, there are no busy loops in LuaLanes. If you try to `linda:receive()` on a key with no value, LuaLanes [puts the reading thread on a wait](https://github.com/LuaDist/lanes/blob/master/src/lanes.c#L462) until the linda object is modified. So the general way for a thread to handle the messages is as follows:

```
local lanes = require "lanes"
local linda = lanes.linda()
local thread = lanes.gen("*", function()
    print("Starting thread...")
    while true do
        local command = linda:receive("cmd")
        if command=="quit" then
            break
        else
            -- do processing based on command
        end
    end
end)

local threads = {}
local NCORES = 4
for i=1,NCORES do threads[i] = thread() end     -- start the threads
-- send messages, like files for processing, using linda:send("cmd", {file=..., op=...})
for i=1,NCORES do linda:send("cmd", "quit") end -- send the quit command
for i=1,NCORES do threads[i]:join() end         -- wait for the threads to end
```

Comment: You created the exact opposite of what I meant. But skipping ahead over that. Is there a way to say send an object and than collect it or read it some time later, say 5min even. As long as its not read the same milisecond its being send which requires a "busy loop" or one which puts it on wait. And not by using a busy loop either. Just a simple example, thread sends an object some time later I may collect/read it or not and using a single "receive" or something alike for example.

Comment: I still do not quite understand what you want. Do you mean that you want to start the thread with an argument ("send an object") process it in a thread and return processed object from the thread ("read it later")? This is supported directly by LuaLanes, you just pass the argument as `thread(object)`, and you can read the first return value by `threads[i][1]` anytime later.

Comment: No, I mean "while" its running. It won't quit after doing a small thing, it is a continues loop. The thread itself. And while that occurs I need to send its data so that either the main thread or another thread can read from it, and use it.

Comment: Then you need to use what I have written. Linda objects are the only way to communicate between threads. Each thread runs in a different Lua state, therefore does not have access to variables of other threads. Only at the thread creation, upvalues (nonlocal variables) are copied to the thread, that is why you can access the linda in the worker thread. To get data into the thread while running, you *have* to use lindas and messages. I do not understand why you want to avoid it.

Comment: No that doesn't work. You misunderstood the use of it. But thats ok, from your writing it seems not possible.

Comment: Maybe you should try to answer why don't you want to send messages. Updating the question with a pseudocode of what you want to achieve (even though not Lua) might help to better understand your requirements.