# lua_xmove between different lua states

Tags: lua

According to the lua 5.1 manual, `lua_xmove` moves values between stacks of different threads belonging to the same Lua state. But, I accidentally happened to use it to move values across different Lua states and it seemed to work fine! Is there any other API to move values from one Lua state to another (in 5.1), or can `lua_xmove` be used?

Comment: One of the ways moving/copying Lua objects between different `Lua States` on different threads:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9573063/1150918

Comment: I grok'd the *LuaLanes* code and I am seeing the code that is doing a copy-over from one state to another. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua stores garbage collection data in the global state. So, if you move GC or string objects across states, you can potentially confuse the garbage collector and create dangling references.

So, while it might look like it works, it could just as easily cause problems later on.

For reference, see [this mailing list thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-07/msg00020.html) where developers discuss this exact issue.

Note that [`lua_xmove`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lapi.c.html#lua_xmove) does check that the global states are the same:

```
api_check(from, G(from) == G(to));
```

Comment: Note that `api_check` changes behavior based on compile time options. See chapter 3 of the manual (ch 4 in 5.2) and luaconf.h. I believe the normal release builds of Lua don't enable the API checks.

Comment: The intent of the api check is crystal clear, `from` should be equal to `to`.

Comment: What?   No, `from` should not be equal to `to`, that would result in a no-op.   What is true is that the global state (the one that resulted from a call to `lua_newstate()` in the state tree must be the same for both arguments.   In other words, both `to` and `from` resulted from a (possibly empty) chain of `lua_newthread()` calls rooted on some initial state `L`.